# Issue fortiOS when creating a srcintf "any" with vip as destination

Tags: fortigate

I have to create the following policy:

```
config firewall policy
edit 0
set srcintf "any"
set dstintf "interface2"
set srcaddr "all"
set dstaddr "vip1"
set action accept
set schedule "always"
set service "ALL"
set logtraffic all
end
```

Existing VIP is:

```
    config firewall vip
    edit "vip1"
        set uuid xxxxx
        set extip 10.1.0.43
        set extintf "interface1"
        set mappedip "x.x.70.9"
    next
    end
```

Which is mapped to:

get router info routing-table details x.x.70.9
Routing entry for x.x.70.0/27
Known via "static", distance 10, metric 0, best

- 10.10.70.1, via "interface2"

But when I create the policy, it only lets me put "interface1" as srcintf.
This does not work for me as I need an 'srcintf "any"' policy.

Error code is 651.

Anyone sees what I'm missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Change the VIP interface to "any". Then you can chose "any" as sourceinterface in the policy as well.

In your example:

```
config firewall vip
    edit "vip_name1"
        set extip 10.1.0.43
        set extintf "any" <---
        set mappedip "x.x.70.9"
    next
end
```